# How to draw lines with its shadow is the weight or frequency of it in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[The width of the grey area represents the frequency of the corresponding type. The maximum frequency 1.0 has a width of 0.1 as the starting types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3P43.png)

I am trying to use python to draw a picture like this. It look more intuitive with the weight added to the related line in a shadow-like way. But I have no idea how to realise it.

Comment: Could you add some example data? And some minimal code you tried? Even the code to generate the main plot without the shaded areas would help a lot in obtaining helpful answers. With 'shadow-like' do you mean only under the curve, nothing above?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do stuff like this using [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html), with a low `alpha` (opacity of the shadow) and given the lower and upper bounds of the shaded area, which I'm assuming you could calculate from the frequency.